# Angular 2 CanActivate as promise, that resolves from another component

Tags: angular, promise, observable

I am trying to resolve canActivate hook from another component and injected service, but something stuck.
Guard and workers service are provided and working fine alone. (Returning *true* form guard resloves the route. Subscribing on workers emitters fires successful.)
The code is:
 **workers.service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class WorkersService {
public mainCmpState: EventEmitter<any>;
constructor() {
   this.mainCmpState = new EventEmitter();
}
toggleMainCmpState(bool) {
    console.log('TOGGLE MAIN CMP' , bool);
    this.mainCmpState.emit(bool);
}
```

**guard.service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class GuardService implements CanActivate {
   constructor(public workers: WorkersService) {}

   canActivate() {
        console.log('CAN ACTIVATE IS CALLED');
        return Observable.create(observer => {
         this.workers.mainCmpState.subscribe((data) => {
                console.log('CAN ACTIVATE SUB', data);

                observer.next(true);
                observer.complete();
        });
    });
}
```

**some.component.ts**

```
//on some test button click
this.workers.toggleMainCmpState(true);
```

What i'm doing wrong? I was tried with Promises too.

Comment: why don't you just return `canActivate() { return this.workers.mainCmpState }` ?

Comment: Maxime, because canActivate() accepts Observable<boolean>|Promise<boolean>|boolean https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/CanActivate-interface.html

Comment: I know that, but if you `subscribe` subscribe to `this.workers.mainCmpState`, then I can imagine that `this.workers.mainCmpState` IS an observable. Then you wrap that into an other observable that you build on your own and emit from it when the other as a new value. That's why I asked : Why don't you just return the `mainCmpState` in the first place ?

Comment: Sorry, I'm a little confused.. If `return this.workers.mainCmpState.subscribe(res => {return res}` - and then call `this.workers.toggleMainCmpState(true)` - nothing happens...

Comment: In addition - event fires everywhere else, but not in GuardService.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What I was trying to explain in previous comments is that wrapping the subscription of an observable inside a newly created observable is not necessary.

If we were comparing that to Promise :

What you're doing here is something like that :

```
  canActivate() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.somePromiseYouAlreadyHave.then(() => {
        resolve(true)
      })
    })
  }
```

What you should be doing :

```
  canActivate() {
    return this.somePromiseYouAlreadyHave;
    // assuming this promise will be resolve with value true
  }
```

Going back to our Observable, instead of doing :

```
  canActivate() {
    console.log('CAN ACTIVATE IS CALLED');
    return Observable.create((observer: Subject<boolean>) => {
      this.workers.mainCmpState.subscribe(res => {
        observer.next(true);
      })
    });
  }
```

you should do :

```
return canActivate() {
  return this.workers.mainCmpState;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, my bad.. I just need to sleep more. I was confused about subscriptions.

Comment: No problem, as long as you understood :)